# how to fake the built-in application switch animation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

I have two views in my app and I want to switch them foreground or background with animation. I like the way iOS does it when I fast-switch between applications (double tap the home button and tap any app).

Is it possible to use that animation directly? (It's OK if it's private, I am not selling my app, just for study purpose.)

If not, is there a way to implement that animation myself? References or examples are very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Leo

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's possible and it's not private. Here you go https://github.com/Split82/HMGLTransitions